# Can't download Visual Studio Installer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to install the Visual Studio Community Edition.
Unfortunately the Installer can't be downloaded. When I look at the logs I get the following messages:

> [12/17/2020, 10:31:35] The entire Box execution exiting with result code: 0x0
> [12/17/2020, 10:31:35] Launched extracted application exiting with result code: 0x138b

The bootstrapper can't access the file at C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages_bootstrapper\vs_installer\sjbe34w.nig and throws a System.UnauthorizedAccessException.

I allready tried, deleting the Packages Folder and clearing the Temp Folder and running the install-programm as administrator. I also allready cheked my Windows Managment INtrsument in services.msc, and it is running and starts automatically. As I am installing Visual Studio on a computer from my work place I can't stop the antivirus-software.

The permissions on the Package-Folder should actually allow the Software to access it, so I'm confused.

Comment: Speak to your IT department at work as there may be some policy preventing the installation of non-work approved software.

Comment: The installation at the computer of my colleague proceeded without problems. So I think that this is not the case, but I will contact them anyway.